# I can't get object from one Activity to another (android)

Tags: android, object, android-activity

I want to pass my object `oManagement` from activity X to Y.

In X:

```
oManagement = new OrdersManagement();
myIntent = new Intent(this, Y.class);
```

Then I fill my oManagement object with separate thread.

Then I am waiting when oManagement filled and start another activity:

```
while (oManagement.allOrders.size() == 0) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (oManagement.allOrders.size() > 0) {
        myIntent.putExtra("OrdersManagementObject", oManagement);
        this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

And in my Y Activity:

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    oManagement = b.getParcelable("OrdersManagementObject");
}
```

And now surprise -> `oManagement` is not `null`, but `oManagement.allOrders.size()` is 0! :( So i pass my object, but `ArrayList` inside by object is 0 (in moment of passing was 1 element inside that Array).

How to fix that?

EDIT:

OrdersManagement class:

```
public class OrdersManagement implements Parcelable {

    public ArrayList<QuantorsOrder> allOrders  = new ArrayList<QuantorsOrder>();

    public OrdersManagement() {
    }

    public OrdersManagement(Parcel in) {
    }

    public static final Creator<OrdersManagement> CREATOR = new Creator<OrdersManagement>() {
        @Override
        public OrdersManagement createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new OrdersManagement(in);
        }

        @Override
        public OrdersManagement[] newArray(int size) {
            return new OrdersManagement[size];
        }
    };

    public void updateListOfOrders(JSONArray jsonArray) throws JSONException {
        if (jsonArray != null && jsonArray.length() > 0)
        {
            JSONObject json;
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                json = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i);
                if(!IsOrderAlreadyExists(json))
                    addOrder(json);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean IsOrderAlreadyExists(JSONObject json) throws JSONException
    {
        if (allOrders.isEmpty())
            return false;
        else
        {
            for(QuantorsOrder order : allOrders)
            {
                if (String.valueOf(order.getId()).equals(json.get("id").toString()))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void addOrder(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        allOrders.add(new QuantorsOrder(json));
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    }
}
```

Comment: We probably need to see the source for the `OrdersManagement` class. Possible that there is a parceling problem there.

Comment: It appears your `startActivity()` resides in an infinite loop

Comment: check how you are extracting the key in your second activity. I will declare the key like this in first activity.                                                                    public final static String EXTRA_ORDERSMANAGEMENT = "OrdersManagementObject";                                                                         Then i will extract the key in second activity like this                                                                                                                    Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras(MainActivity.EXTRA_ORDERSMANAGEMENT);

Comment: How does `while (oManagement.allOrders.size() == 0)` work when you have `if (oManagement.allOrders.size() > 0)` inside that loop?

Comment: could you show OrdersManagement class ?

Comment: @cricket_007 Wouldn't it work if `oManagement.notify()` is called from somewhere?

Comment: @KNeerajLal I don't know, but this isn't a [mcve], so it's hard to give any answer

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: `public OrdersManagement(Parcel in) {}` - you expect the object created by this constructor to contain something?

Comment: You need to write code for parceling and deparcelling the object in `OrdersManagement(Parcel in)` constructor and `writeToParcel` method.

Comment: How to do that? I implement that interface because i have to pass object between activities and second method i found (serializable) cant work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550714/passing-objects-between-activities-in-android?rq=1 Hope this SO will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Your `QuantorsOrder`should also implement Parcelable.
And in `writeToParcel()` method you should write the list and read it in constructor like this:

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeTypedList(allOrders);
}

private OrdersManagement (Parcel in) {
    in.readTypedList(allOrders, QuantorsOrder.CREATOR);
}
```

You should also implement the logic of writing and reading field in your `QuantorsOrder` class.
Here is example on simple class:

```
   public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {
     private int mData;

     public int describeContents() {
         return 0;
     }

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
         out.writeInt(mData);
     }

     public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR
             = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {
         public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
             return new MyParcelable(in);
         }

         public MyParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
             return new MyParcelable[size];
         }
     };

     public MyParcelable(Parcel in) {
         mData = in.readInt();
     }
 }
```

The main thing here is happening in `writeToParcel(...)` method and in constructor `public MyParcelable(Parcel in)`.